# Weird issue with 2 JPanels

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, jlayeredpane

I have a JFrame containing a JLayeredPane which contains 2 JPanels, one on top of the other.

The JPanel at the front is a simple GridLayout with some buttons.

The JPanel at the back is an image which has to change regularly. It's basically a snapsnot from the camera and has to update a few times a second.

To draw the image on this JPanel regularly I'm calling this updateImage method:

```
public void updateImage(Image image)
{
    if(image == null) return;
    setSize(image.getWidth(null),image.getHeight(null));
    this.image = image;
    this.repaint();
}

@Override
public void paintComponent(Graphics g)  
{   
    super.paintComponent(g);
    g.drawImage(image,0,0,null); 
}
```

However, every time paintComponent is called, the panel at the front is hidden.

I've tried several different things, the closest I've gotten to making this work is by calling:

```
((JLayeredPane)this.getParent()).setLayer(this, 0);
```

at the bottom of the paintComponent method. This works, but it's horribly slow.

What else can I do?

By the way, this isn't an issue with JLayeredPane, I've tried this with a couple of other layout managers and basically every time it still hides the panel at the back.

Thanks very much in advance for any suggestions!

Comment: Do you call the updateImage() method on the EDT? Did you try using a JLabel instead of a custom component to paint the image? Did you try the OverlayLayout? If you need more help then post a proper SSCCE because the code posted is not detailed enough to see what you might be doing wrong.

Comment: It's Impossible to tell, however, why not set the background panels layout to BorderLayout and add the top panel to it. Also, make sure that the top panel is transparent (setOpaque(false))

Comment: Also there is no need for multiple layers. Just paint the image on your panel and then add components to the same panel. Or use a JLabel as your container and just set the layout of the label to use a GridLayout and add components to it directly.

Comment: Oh wow, using a JLabel worked! Thanks!